# Identify all $_POST & $_GET entries in PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing a basic WAF and I'm up to the moment when I have to identify the attack vectors. When I'm detecting SQL injection or any other sort of intrusion attempt I need to check data submitted through every `$_POST` and `$_GET` input.

Besides, checking each header or input individually is there a way to inspect all at once?

Comment: `foreach` over `$_POST` & `$_GET`

Comment: So: `$array = array($_POST, $_GET); foreach($array as $element){run a check}`

Comment: @user3794668 no, iterate `$_POST` and `$_GET` separately. If you make an array of them, it will be a 2D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST as $val) {
    // check $val
}
foreach ($_GET as $val) {
    // check $val
}
```

You need to process each array separately. If you try to merge them (either with `array_merge` or with the pre-merged `$_REQUEST` array), you'll skip duplicate keys.

Comment: Would it be a good idea if I use `$_REQUEST` and apply one `foreach` for just it since it also goes through `$_COOKIE`?

Comment: No, because that will skip keys that are duplicated in `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: Cookies shouldn't be in `$_REQUEST`. That's a php.ini option that should be turned off.

Comment: So in short I should foreach each independently. Thanks for the help - answer accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

yes, use the sanitize filters in php, they work on arrays like $_REQUEST etc.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( array_merge($_POST, $_GET) as $Input)
{
    check($Input);
}
```

Comment: If there are duplicate keys in `$_POST` and `$_GET`, this will ignore the one in `$_POST`.